# javascript based shopping cart - Securing the price attribue

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to update a javascript based shopping cart. The products are listed like

```
<ul>
  <li class="product" data-price="5.00">
    <h2>Product Name</h2>
    <p> Product Descriptions>
    ....
    <a href="#" onclick="addToCart">$ 5.00</a>
  </li>
  <li class="product" data-price="6.70">
    <h2>Product Name</h2>
    <p> Product Descriptions>
    ....
    <a href="#" onclick="addToCart">$ 6.70</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and in schopping cart we read `data-price` to get the price. This means if the user changes this attribute in Firebug or any other tool the price is automatically changed in cart.

I can't rewrite the whole cart, but would also like to secure the price logic. What are the alternatives to resolve this issue

Comment: You can fetch the actual price from the database while inserting instead of relying on the data attribute.

Comment: Never trust the client to give you the correct price! Or to give you anything else correct, for that matter.

Comment: you should use like the product name, i ll supose it is unique, and then go into your database and you get the price yourself, its not the best ideia aswell, but atleast if the client mess with the name you will find no matches in the db and you will realize something is wrong

Comment: @rule `product name` cannot be considered as unique. And you cannot search database over `product name` to get the price it has to be on `product id`.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala, ye you right , was just trying to figure out a way of explaining the process to look into the db instead of trying to get it from user, didnt went well, thanks for the save tho!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need some sort of server side validation to ensure the price is never manipulated by the client. If you're trying to do the entire basket and checkout system client side then there's, to my best knowledge, nothing you can do to prevent a user manipulating the content. You can make it harder for them to do so, but never impossible to.

The securest way, and the way I'd do it, is to only store the product ids in the basket. So when a user clicks "Add to cart" you just add the product id. Whenever you need to calculate the basket total or get the price for individual products in it you can just loop through the product ids and match them up to prices that you have explicitly defined somewhere.

Ideally you'd do this server side and have the prices in a database, or something similar. That way it's, for all intents and purposes, impossible for them to manipulate the prices. The worst they can do is manipulate the product ids in the basket and then all they'd end up doing is paying for the wrong thing, but since they are going out their way to try to break your system that's their problem and not yours.

If you really can't do this server side, for whatever reason, then you could instead hardcode the product prices into a javascript file and check the ids that way. It's less secure than doing it server side but it will be far harder to manipulate the contents of an javascript file within you webpage than to edit the properties of dom elements.

Here's a very very simple example using the frontend only implementation:

```
var products = {
    1: 5.99,
    2: 7.99,
    3: 2.50
};

var basket = [];

function addToBasket(productId) {
    basket.push(productId);
}

function getBasketTotal() {

    var total = 0;

    basket.forEach(function(productId) {
        total += products[productId];
    });

    return total;
}
```